# C# Localization = true cause "Code generation for property 'Text' failed."

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a solution that has been around for 20+ years. I have boiled down my issue to the bare minimum: If I create a clean and unedited Windows form I am unable to change the Localization to True without getting prompted and being unable to save:

*Code generation for property 'Text' failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

This occurs only if the form is in a specific project/namespace. If I move the files to a different project with namespace changed, it works. Creating a new form in any other project works as intended.

The 'Text' refers to the title variable which is in every form.

It creates a (1) .resx file but does not appear to use it. Atleast, I am unable to have multiple languages (no .en.resx or other).

So... How could a form be affected by simply be in the same project/namespace whilst being so bareboned? Thoughts?

Comment: So what is this namespace name that appears to break resource generation? Is it `Resources`? Can you debug the code generation (attach another VS instance to yours)?

Comment: My project(and namespace) is called CommonSolutionNameClasses. It does have a folder named Resources with SolutionNameResource.resx (and .en.resx.)
Im unsure what you mean with the "debug the code generation". Should I attach with another VS to the first visual studio? I did that and got: Exception thrown at 0x7627FD82 (KernelBase.dll) in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

edit: nothing valuable in call stack.

Comment: I started deleting things in the solution until it started working. When the "SolutionNameResource.resx" got deleted it started working again. So I guess that is the root of the issue. Still dont know yet what will solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project has another resx that has been around for some time and had gotten corrupted by migration to newer Visual studio versions. I found a page somewhere which pointed out this could've occured at around ~vs2005. Regardless, in my case, I manually deleted these rows in the resx files which was in the project (which was not the resx-files for the forms I wanted to change things in).

```
  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <data name="CommonMyProjectGui" type="System.Resources.ResXNullRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value />
  </data>
```

Then it worked again.

Note; the comments I found talked about other variables couldve been affected so divide and conquer the variables and to see any other variables are affected.